# select query with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables: `dba_account` and `dba_account_password`. Now I am trying to populate information from both tables.I am using this query.

```
SELECT da.account_name, da.account_id, da.status, da.manager_firstname, 
dap.live_password_change, dap.dev_password_change FROM dba_account da INNER JOIN 
dba_account_password dap ON da.account_id = dap.account_id
```

Now, the thing is dba_account has 1328 number of records(account_name), and dba_account_password only has 270 records. When I run this query it only displays 270 records. but I also want to display other usernames too(ones that are not in dba_account_password). any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT da.account_name, 
    da.account_id, 
    da.status, 
    da.manager_firstname, 
    dap.live_password_change, 
    dap.dev_password_change 
FROM dba_account da 
LEFT JOIN dba_account_password dap 
    ON da.account_id = dap.account_id
```

An `INNER JOIN` will only give you the records that match in both tables.  Here is a good [Visual Explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use left join in this case

```
SELECT da.account_name, da.account_id, da.status, da.manager_firstname, 
dap.live_password_change, dap.dev_password_change FROM dba_account da LEFT JOIN 
dba_account_password dap ON da.account_id = dap.account_id
```

**Small description of left join**

**

```
table 1
userid  username
1        ABC
2        PQR
3        DEF
table2
userid  userRole
1       ACCOUNTANT
2       HO

RESULT OF LEFT JOIN :-

 left join on table1.userid=table2.userid
    userid   username  userrole
    1        ABC        ACCOUNTANT
    2        PQR        HO
    3        DEF

**
```